# Stripe don't work on IWD OPC

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I use IWD OPC and the module pay with stripe, but this is not working. When I click on "place order", it is showing loading, but nothing is happening after that.

You can check the issue on [growerline.com](http://growerline.com)

Have any idea for fix this?

Comment: it seems this is javascript error. You have take invalid element for stripe. You can check  and debug error using firebug.

Comment: @JaiminParikh, do you fix this for me by payment?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
var cvcValue=$('stripe_cc_cid').value;
```

instead of

```
var cvcValue=$('stripe_cc_cvc').value;
```

in you js.

Also you can refer @https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form for create stripe token.

Comment: Very thanks, where I can change it? Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: Maybe in skin/frontend/base/default/js/iwd/opc/checkout.js ?

Comment: yes, you can change it form checkout.js

Comment: I edit this but the issue persist.

Comment: You have also take wrong ids for month and year in js. Please use var exp_monthValue=$('stripe_expiration').value;
var exp_yearValue=$('stripe_expiration_yr').value; ..... It will resolved your issue and make sure all element ids which you take in js is proper

Comment: I edit the id for month and year in checkout.js, but the issue persist, do you have another solution? Thanks!

Comment: it seems issue is related to stripe credentials or generate invalid publishable key. Please refer @ https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form for stripe errors.

Comment: Credential are ok, but I use the secret key not the publishable.