# 500 Internal Server Error during onepage checkout saveShippingMethod

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, ajax, json

Hi I have problem in my onepage checkout. I can't choose pay method because ajax all time is reload. In console I have 500 (Internal Server Error)  (in adress onepage/json/saveShippingMethod. I can't find this controller. In exception log I have 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message

> 'Mage registry key "themeMediaUrl" already exists' in
>   /var/www/home/mmuzyka/byinsomniabiz/app/Mage.php:595. Do you have any
>   hints?

edit: I have the same issue and I change code from this case but not work. [Stripe don't work on IWD OPC](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125521/stripe-dont-work-on-iwd-opc)

Comment: put ajax request url here.

Comment: Search for word `themeMediaUrl` recursively inside `app/code/community/` and `app/code/local/` folders. You may find something wrong there.